# hide and show div with unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to hide and show a div (filter-panel--content) with an unordered list in it, when clicking on the label above.

```
#LABEL/DIV WHICH CAN BE CLICKED AND THE .click() SHOULD FIRE
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
   <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label></div>

#DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
<div class="filter-panel--content">
   <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
      <div class="option--container">
         <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__575" name="__f__575" value="575">
         </span>
      <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__575">8</label>
      </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div></div>

#LABEL/DIV WHICH CAN BE CLICKED AND THE .click() SHOULD FIRE
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
   <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label></div>

#DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
<div class="filter-panel--content">
   <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
      <div class="option--container">
         <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__576" name="__f__576" value="576">
         </span>
      <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__576">9</label>
      </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

#LABEL/DIV WHICH CAN BE CLICKED AND THE .click() SHOULD FIRE
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
   <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label></div>

#DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
<div class="filter-panel--content">
   <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
      <div class="option--container">
         <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__577" name="__f__577" value="577">
         </span>
      <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__577">10</label>
      </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my click() function, which toggle's the class (changing a backgroundimage) and additionally i want to hide and show the clicked filter-panel--content:

```
$('.label-it').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".filter-panel--title div").toggleClass('klapp klappe');
  //hide and show filter-panel--content
  //tried something like this but it doesn't worked: 
  //$(this).find(".filter-panel--content div").hide();
});
```

But it should only closes the clicked label filter-panel--content, not every class of it. Can someone help? Thank you!

-- edit:

i have a additional question, the toggle works fine `$(this).closest(".filter-panel--flyout").find(".filter-panel--content div")` but when i submit my inputs, the display:none classes will be refreshed and it is display:block.. how can i submit my toggled `.filter-panel--content` so that it stays toggled?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$(this).find(".filter-panel--content div")` because `filter-panel--content` is not a child of `label-it`.

So in order to make it work, you have to use `.closest()` like as in `$(this).closest(".filter-panel--flyout").find(".filter-panel--content div")`

**Demo**

```js
$('.label-it').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".filter-panel--title div").toggleClass('klapp klappe');
  $(this).closest(".filter-panel--flyout").find(".filter-panel--content").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
  <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
  </div>

  #DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
  <div class="filter-panel--content">
    <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
        <div class="option--container">
          <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__575" name="__f__575" value="575">
         </span>
          <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__575">8</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

#LABEL/DIV WHICH CAN BE CLICKED AND THE .click() SHOULD FIRE
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
  <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label>
  </div>

  #DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
  <div class="filter-panel--content">
    <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
        <div class="option--container">
          <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__576" name="__f__576" value="576">
         </span>
          <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__576">9</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

#LABEL/DIV WHICH CAN BE CLICKED AND THE .click() SHOULD FIRE
<div class="filter-panel--flyout">
  <div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title">
      <h3 class="rums">Ports</h3><div id="klapp" class="klapp"></div>
   </label></div>

  #DIV WHICH SHOULD show AND hide WHEN LABEL IS CLICKED
  <div class="filter-panel--content">
    <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
      <li class="filter-panel--option">
        <div class="option--container">
          <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="__f__577" name="__f__577" value="577">
         </span>
          <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__577">10</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JohnDoe No problem, happy to help.

Comment: i have a additional question, the toggle works fine but when i submit my inputs, the display:none classes will be refreshed and it is display:block.. how can i submit my toggled .filter-panel--content so that it stays toggled?

Comment: @JohnDoe When you submit, you automatic refresh the page, so you would have to look into sessions.